# sql developer run script with grid result

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i open the script results script. I tried cntrl + enter. all i get is text based results.

Comment: Huh?  Please clarify your question.  Not at all clear.  Read [ask].

Comment: When I run my sql nothing shows. There is no "query results " tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F9 or ctrl-enter get you to the query results grid view. Hopefully this helps